# Copying contents of uint8_t[] into an NSString

Tags: objective-c, io, objective-c++

I have a uint_8[] array of characters and I'd like to convert it to an NSString but I'm getting NULL back. What's the proper way to convert between these two types?

```
// Defined else where as:
uint8_t someValue[8];
```

someValue is not NULL and contains some valid characters

I've tried:

```
NSLog(@"converted using CString: %@", [NSString stringWithCString:(char const *)someValue encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

as well as:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[data appendBytes:someValue length:sizeof(someValue)];
converted = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"converted using NSData: %@", converted);
```

Comment: Is the content of `someValue` null-terminated?

Comment: `someValue` is an array - how could it be NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
[NSString stringWithCString:(char const *)someValue encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

only works if there is a null terminator in the `someValue` array.

Your other solution doesn't work because `sizeof(someValue)` does not return the number of characters in the array, it returns the size of the `uint8_t` pointer.

You can use:

```
NSUInteger len = ... // the actual number of characters in someValue
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:someValue length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Of course this requires that you know how many characters are really in the array.

Comment: I'm getting the length using: size_t len = sizeof(someValue)/sizeof(someValue[0]);
contents of someValue:
(uint8_t)
[0] = '\xb3'
[1] = '\x90'
[2] = '0'
[3] = '\0'
[4] = '\0'
[5] = '\n'
[6] = '\xa3'
[7] = '\x18'

Comment: @Will (Shall I fire?) - That string contains nulls, and that will confound most translations to UTF.  What does the string represent?  Is it supposed to be character data, or something else?  (You should only put character data in an NSString.)

Comment: `'\xb3'` is not the start of any valid UTF-8 sequence, so any conversion to NSString with `encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` will immediately fail.

Comment: It looks like the incoming data had some snafus. The above suggestion worked with correct string values.